# Evaluating $\int \:\sqrt{1+e^x}dx$ , why I got different answers?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I've got 2 steps to evaluating $\int \:\sqrt{1+e^x}dx$ which lead to different values

> first step :

$\int \:\sqrt{1+e^x}dx$

let $u\:=\:\sqrt{1+e^x}$ , $du\:=\:\frac{e^x}{2\sqrt{1+e^x}}dx$ , but $e^x\:=\:u^2-1$ and substitute $u$ into $du$, i get $dx\:=\:\frac{2u}{u^2-1}du$

thus, $\int \:\sqrt{1+e^x}dx$ $=2\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-1}du\:$

apply the following algebraic property $\frac{a}{1+a}=-\frac{1}{1+a}+1$ , then the integrand becomes
$\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}=\frac{1}{\:u^2-1}+1$ ,thus

$=2\int \:\:\left(\frac{1}{u^2-1}+1\right)du\:=\:-2arctanh\left(u\right)\:+\:2u\:+C$

substitute back $u$, thus

$\int \:\sqrt{1+e^x}dx=2\sqrt{1+e^x}-2arctanh\left(\sqrt{1+e^x}\right)+C$

> 2nd step :

using the same substitution for $u$ , $du$, and $dx$

$\int \:\sqrt{1+e^x}dx$ $=\int \frac{2u^2}{u^2-1}du\:$ $=\int \:\left(2\:+\:\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right)du$

evaluating the integrand one by one, then i get

$=2u\:+ln\left(u-1\right)-ln\left(u+1\right)\:+C\:=\:2u\:+\:ln\left(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)\:+\:C$

substitute back $u$, thus the answer becomes

$\int \:\sqrt{1+e^x}dx=2\sqrt{1+e^x}+ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+e^x}-1}{\sqrt{1+e^x}+1}\right)+C$

> when i do derivative to both answers, i got the same answer which is $\sqrt{1+e^x}$ , it makes me confused which step is the right one? thanks for you answer. :)

EDIT :

> Thank you for the answers, now i get it that both answers are correct. :)

Comment: Both answers look the same...

Comment: *why I got different answers?* - You didn't. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $y = \tanh^{-1} x$.  Then $$x = \tanh y = \frac{\sinh y}{\cosh y} = \frac{(e^y - e^{-y})/2}{(e^y + e^{-y})/2} = \frac{e^{2y} - 1}{e^{2y}+1}.$$  Hence $(e^{2y}+1)x = e^{2y}-1$, or $e^{2y}(1-x) = x+1$, or $$e^{2y} = \frac{1+x}{1-x}.$$  It follows that $$y = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1+x}{1-x} = \tanh^{-1}x.$$

Comment: thank you for this proof, it's really helpful! thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly normal. It seems just that you forgot that we can rewrite $$\tanh ^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$ Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function where you will find other very useful identities for inverse hyperbolic functions.

Comment: it's not that i forgot but i really didn't know if there's logarithmic representation for this kind of hyperbolic function. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You are welcome. This formulas are very easy to establish.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\ln t$ so we have $$\int \sqrt{1+e^x}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+t}}{t}dt$$ now consider $1+t=u^2$ so we have $$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+t}}{t}dt=\int \frac{2u^2}{1-u^2}du$$ from here you can solve.